# SelectFromModel from sklearn gives significantly different features on random forest and gradient boosting classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

As mentioned in the title, Im using SelectFromModel from sklearn to select features for both my random forest and gradient boosting classification models.

```
#feature selection performed on training dataset to prevent overfitting
sel = SelectFromModel(GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=10, learning_rate=0.25,max_depth=1, max_features = 15, random_state=0).fit(X_train_bin, y_train))
sel.fit(X_train_bin, y_train)

#returns a boolean array to indicate which features are of importance (above the mean threshold)
sel.get_support()

#shows the names of the selected features
selected_feat= X_train_bin.columns[(sel.get_support())]
selected_feat
```

The boolean array that is returned for random forest and gradient boosting model are COMPLETELY different. random forest feature selection tells me to drop an additional 4 columns (out of 25 features) and the feature selection on the gradient boosting model is telling me to drop nearly everything. What is happening here?

EDIT: I'm trying to compare the performance of these 2 models on my dataset. Should I move the threshold so I at least have approximately the same amount of features to train on?

Comment: There is *absolutely no reason* that they should be the same, or even similar. Neither there is any theory behind such feature selection approaches, they are just heuristic tricks that *sometimes* seem to work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on their heuristic nature?

Comment: I am afraid comments in SO is not the appropriate place to do so. Please notice the intro and **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) (actually applicable here, too, despite that you have not tagged your question as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for them to select the same variables. `GradientBoostingClassifier` builds each tree to improve on the error of the previous step, while `RandomForestClassifier` trains independent trees that have nothing to do with each others' errors.

Another reason why they may select different features is `criterion`, which is entropy for Random Forests and Friedman MSE for Gradient Boosting. Finally, it could be because both algorithms select random subsets of features when making each split. Hence, they did not compare the same variables in the same order, which will naturally yield different importances.